# Spring AMQP client hangs

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

There is a behavior in RabbitMQ server that it will not accept subsequent connections / operations when it reaches to watermark value till the time it rebalances itself. 
RabbitMQ client elegantly gets timeout when such situations happen after the connection timeout , But we are using Spring AMQP it continues to hang.

**Steps to Reproduce**

o   Create a RabbitMQ HA cluster

o   Create a simple program which produces and consumes message

- a)  Using Spring AMQP
- b)  Using RabbitMQ client

o   Make RabbitMQ server reach high watermark value in memory so that it cannot accept any new connections or perform any operations say for 10 min

o   Create Q, Send message from

- a)   Spring AMQP ( It will hang )
- b)   RabbitMQ client ( It will get timeout ) say after 1 min if connection timeout is being set as 1 min.

**Spring Binaries Version**

a) spring-rabbit-1.6.7.RELEASE.jar

b) spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar

c) spring-amqp-1.6.7.RELEASE.jar

We tried upgrading to Spring Rabbit and AMQP 2.0.2 version as well , But it didn’t helped.

Comment: This is a bug report, not a question. Can you reformat it to fit the Q&A format of the site? I'm not sure what your issue is... you don't say what the expected behavior is, nor is any code provided.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a bug report, not a question.

Answer (score 2):

You don't describe what your "RabbitMQ Client" is, but the java `amqp-client` uses classic Sockets by default. So you should get the same behavior with both (since Spring AMQP uses that client). Perhaps you are referring to some other language client.

With java `Socket`s, when the connection is blocked, the thread is "stuck" in socket write which is not interruptible, nor does it timeout.

To handle this condition, you have to use [the 4.0 client or above](https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2016/11/24/rabbitmq-java-client-4-0-is-released/) and use NIO.

Here is an example application that demonstrates the technique.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So48699178Application {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(So48699178Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So48699178Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(RabbitTemplate template, CachingConnectionFactory ccf) {
        ConnectionFactory cf = ccf.getRabbitConnectionFactory();
        NioParams nioParams = new NioParams();
        nioParams.setWriteEnqueuingTimeoutInMs(20_000);
        cf.setNioParams(nioParams);
        cf.useNio();
        return args -> {
            Message message = MessageBuilder.withBody(new byte[100_000])
                    .andProperties(MessagePropertiesBuilder.newInstance()
                            .setDeliveryMode(MessageDeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT)
                            .build())
                    .build();
            while (true) {
                try {
                    template.send("foo", message);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.info(e.getMessage());
                }
            }

        };

    }

    @Bean
    public Queue foo() {
        return new Queue("foo");
    }

}
```

and

> 2018-02-09 12:00:29.803  INFO 9430 --- [           main] com.example.So48699178Application        : java.io.IOException: Frame enqueuing failed
>
> 2018-02-09 12:00:49.803  INFO 9430 --- [           main] com.example.So48699178Application        : java.io.IOException: Frame enqueuing failed
>
> 2018-02-09 12:01:09.807  INFO 9430 --- [           main] com.example.So48699178Application        : java.io.IOException: Frame enqueuing failed

Comment: Gary Russell -- I implemented this approach but still threads are in waiting state. Please find below stacktrace :-    java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
 at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 - waiting on <0x000000071b4daeb8> (a com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException)
 at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingCell.get(BlockingCell.java:73)
 - locked <0x000000071b4daeb8> (a com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException)
 at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingCell.uninterruptibleGet(BlockingCell.java:120)

Comment: at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:2106)
 at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2058)
 at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.send(RabbitTemplate.java:1004)
 at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(RabbitTemplate.java:1110)
 at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(RabbitTemplate.java:1101)

Comment: Don't put stack traces in comments; it's unreadable and incomplete. And, don't comment on 2.5 year old answers. Ask a new question showing code, configuration, versions and FULL stack trace. The only time I've seen a hang there is when trying to send a message on the thread that is reporting a returned message (with old versions of the framework), causing a deadlock in the client.

Comment: I have asked new question with all details -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63779597/spring-amqp-client-hangs-when-watermark-value-is-reached. Please have a look at it, thanks in advance.