# Spring AMQP client hangs when watermark value is reached

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

When RabbitMQ server reaches watermark level then client trying to send message to RabbitMQ server is stuck in waiting state. I want Spring AMQP client to timeout after waiting for some time(500ms). Please find below stack trace :-

```
 "pool-3-thread-1" #17 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000002b7ea800 nid=0x5750 in Object.wait() [0x000000002d9fe000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x000000071b4daeb8> (a com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException)
        at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingCell.get(BlockingCell.java:73)
        - locked <0x000000071b4daeb8> (a com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException)
        at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingCell.uninterruptibleGet(BlockingCell.java:120)
        - locked <0x000000071b4daeb8> (a com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException)
        at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:36)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:502)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:293)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:141)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.txCommit(ChannelN.java:1540)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.txCommit(ChannelN.java:52)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedChannelInvocationHandler.invoke(CachingConnectionFactory.java:1190)
        - locked <0x000000071b4b1380> (a java.lang.Object)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy42.txCommit(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.RabbitUtils.commitIfNecessary(RabbitUtils.java:141)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doSend(RabbitTemplate.java:2322)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.lambda$send$3(RabbitTemplate.java:1005)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate$$Lambda$122/1529091234.doInRabbit(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.invokeAction(RabbitTemplate.java:2147)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:2106)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2058)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.send(RabbitTemplate.java:1004)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(RabbitTemplate.java:1110)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(RabbitTemplate.java:1101)
```

I am creating ConnectionFactory bean by using this XML configuration:-

```
<bean id="connectionFactory"
        class="com.example.CustomCachingConnectionFactory">
        <constructor-arg value="#{messagingProperties['mq.hostname']}" />
        <property name="virtualHost" value="#{messagingProperties['mq.virtual-host']}" />
        <property name="username" value="#{messagingProperties['mq.username']}" />
        <property name="password" value="#{messagingProperties['mq.password']}" />
        <property name="channelCacheSize" value="25" />
    </bean>
```

Custom Connection Factory :-

```
public class CustomCachingConnectionFactory extends CachingConnectionFactory {


    private com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory;

    public CustomCachingConnectionFactory(@Nullable String hostname){
        super(hostname);
    }

    @Override
    public ConnectionFactory getRabbitConnectionFactory() {
        rabbitConnectionFactory = super.getRabbitConnectionFactory();
        rabbitConnectionFactory.useNio();
        return rabbitConnectionFactory;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        rabbitConnectionFactory.setNioParams(getNioParams());
    }

    private NioParams getNioParams(){
        NioParams nioParams = new NioParams();
        nioParams.setWriteEnqueuingTimeoutInMs(500);
        return nioParams;
    }
}
```

Please suggest how to stop AMQP client from waiting indefinitely for RabbitMQ server to respond.

amqp-client version -- 5.7.3

spring rabbit version -- 2.2.1.RELEASE
spring amqp version -- 2.2.1.RELEASE
spring core -- 5.2.1.RELEASE

Full thread dump -- https://gist.github.com/CODESTHN/7eedd6881b575977a0e7d69d7228325f

Comment: The stack trace is truncated - you need to show the COMPLETE stack trace, as well as the thread that has locked `<0x000000071b4daeb8>` (Or post the complete thread dump somplace like pastebin or in a GitHub Gist). Also, what version is spring-rabbit?

Comment: I think no other thread has taken lock of <0x000000071b4daeb8>, I have attached complete thread dump, please have a look.

Comment: It looks like it's waiting for a reply to the `txCommit()`. Look in the server logs to see if there are any clues there. If not, I suggest you ask your question on the rabbitmq-users Google group, with a link to that Gist; this does not appear to be anything to do with Spring; it simply invoked `txCommit()` on the channel.

Comment: from [RabbitMQ's documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/memory.html): `By default, when the RabbitMQ server uses above 40% of the available RAM, it raises a memory alarm and blocks all connections that are publishing messages.` I think you'd need to tweak the alarm as explained in that page (I don't see how can you set a timeout from server side)

Comment: @Jose M -- I intentionally triggered the watermark alarm for testing a scenario when Rabbit is not responding because it happens sometimes in PROD. Reducing channelRpcTimeout to 1 minute from default value of 10 minutes, helped me to timeout waiting threads early.